# How can I write a unit test to test the functionality of Thread.Sleep?

Tags: java, unit-testing, thread-sleep

Let's say I implemented a method which sleeps the current thread for 10 seconds. Now I want to write a unit test case to test the functionality of this method. How can I do this? Is the below code a better option?

```
@Test
public void testSleep() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    invokeFunction(2000);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Assert.assertTrue(end - start > 2000);
}
```

Comment: Why are you unit-testing the JVM functions?

Comment: I am not unit testing a JVM function. Rather I'm writing a new programming language on top of JVM and I'm writing my unit tests on Java. I want to test my function in a Java code. It may feel like crazy, but this is a real requirement in my case :)

Comment: @Chanakaudaya You cannot write a programming language on top of JVM because if you are doing so then you have use the same primitives etc. as what JVM understands, and if you do so then you are still in Java programming language, and if you do not do so then you cannot build on top of JVM because those (your own) primitives etc. will not be understood by JVM.

Comment: @hagrawal this is not true, there are plenty of languages, both compiled and interpreted, that are written ontop of the jvm.  There is scala, groovy, and jprolog just to name a few. (I know prolog is its own things, but jprolog runs on the jvm)

Comment: @hagarwal what mentioned is correct. I am currently involved in writing a programming language on top of JVM. That is somewhat similar to Scala or Groovy but with a completely different syntax and semantic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the code you attached is a fine test to test that the duration of `invokeFunction(2000)` does indeed take at least 2000ms. Though, it doesn't prove that the function takes roughly the amount of time you spec.

```
@Test
public void testSleep() {
   for(int i=250; i<3000; i+= 250) {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      invokeFunction(i);
      long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Assert.assertTrue(end - start >= i);
      Assert.assertTrue(end - start <= i+ 250);
   }
}
```

This way you can show that the function takes roughly the amount of time give to it, with a tolerance of 250ms.  With your original test if the `invokeFunction` method was hardcoded to sleep for 5000ms then your test would pass, but the implementation would not actually be correct.

Answer (score 0):

i would say it depends what you want to test. you are not testing that the function actually sleeps thread X seconds, you are testing that the method takes at least X seconds to complete.

I mean, if the function is doing more things than just Thread.sleep, you are counting all of the stuff.

Note that i say at least, since there is no guarantee that the thread will sleep this amount of time exactly; it may take more time to awake (jvm will do its best).

but TBH i don't know of any other better approach than what you are doing, without doing changes in your function implementation just for the sake of being able to test that (like having an intermediate component which only purpose is just to sleep the thread and just monitor enter and exit from that component).